# Alternative to MediaPlayer to play an audio file

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Is there an alternative way of playing audio data other than using MediaPlayer. The audio comes from a resource and not a file. I also want it played from a service and not from an activity or using a built-in music player app. What alternative APIs exist? I am coming to the conclusion after much testing that MediaPlayer in Android 4.1 is buggy and fails much more than under previous versions, so I am looking for an alternative means of playing audio.

Comment: The alternatives in Android that I know of are [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) and [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)

Comment: Have you checked out the code for ServeStream (disclaimer: I created it)? It uses FFmpeg and AudioTrack (in a service!) to provide playback of files not supported natively by Android. Here is a link: http://sourceforge.net/p/servestream/code/1493/tree/

Answer (score 0):

I think the [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) is the best thing to use here. as you are looking to play from resource then you can use raw pcm audio data as resource.

Comment: AudioTrack gets killed after some time on Android 4.1 when operating from a service. The bug has to do with Android 4.1